# powershell reg ex replace whole string with part of string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm rubbish at reg ex's anyway and been trying all day with no success.

input string:

> "fred XY-C4569-32 (Bloggs) 24 acacia (revision 1) road"

I just want to extract

> "fred XY-C4569-32"

fred may be shorter or longer e.g. (ted or william) so i cant just sub string in on an index to do it.

I have been trying stuff like

```
-replace "^([a-z0-9 -]*) ([a-z0-9 \\(\\) -])" , '$1'
```

but no joy so far

thanks

Comment: Try the stuff like `-replace "^(\S+\s+\S+).*" , '$1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, just add `+` or `*` next to the second character class.

```
-replace "^([A-Za-z0-9 -]*\\b) [A-Za-z0-9() -]+" , '$1'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oY2sI2/2)

Comment: That worked Thanks for that.  Any idea why the $1 now gives me
"fred XY-C4569-32."
with a "." now on the end?

Comment: Its Ok I got it now,  I had a . on the end of my string I forgot to put in my orig post.